# How do I properly rename a GitHub repository inside Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github

How do I properly rename a GitHub repository inside Eclipse?
Or do I need to do everthing manually? E.g rename the GitHub repository inside GitHub and then delete my project in Eclipse and do a new clone-repo again?

Comment: I guess after renaming you just have to adapt the fetch and push URLs in your local Git repository configuration (in Eclipse in the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the repository and choose _Properties: Configuration_).

Comment: @howlger And then only change the orgin URL?

Comment: Yes, right, only the "origin" (or how the remote is called) URL needs to be changed, I think.